# How can I make a function use the child object associated function instead of the parent one?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm coding a simple physics engine with a few others for a school assignment. In order to be as generic, we made a Particle class, then an Object class which inherits it (and is basically a particle with a force vector), and finally a Disc class which is a child class of Object.
In my class PyhsicsWorld, I want to use a list of Objects and iterate on it to resolve collisions. For that, I declared the intersects(Object o1, Object o2) and GetPenDist(Object o1, Object o2) functions, but they aren't supposed to be called. Instead, I'm overloading these functions in Disc and I want the program to use these instead.
I only create and use Discs (for now), so I'm sure there isn't any reason (other than me not understanding my code) for the program to call intersects on Objects instead of Disc. Here is my code :

Object.h :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "./Particle.h"

class Object : public Particle {
//Some code
};

bool intersects(Object o1, Object o2);
float getPenDist(Object o1, Object o2);
```

Object.cpp :

```
#include "./Object.h"

bool intersects(Object o1, Object o2) {
    std::cout << "Bad Intersects" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

float getPenDist(Object o1, Object o2) {
    std::cout << "Bad PenDist" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Disc.h :

```
#include "./Object.h"

class Disc : public Object {

protected : 

    float radius;

public :
    float getRadius() { return radius; }

//Some code
};

bool intersects(Disc d1, Disc d2);
float getPenDist(Disc d1, Disc d2);
```

Disc.cpp :

```
#include "./Disc.h"

bool intersects(Disc d1, Disc d2) {
    return (d2.getPosition() - d1.getPosition()).getNorm() < d1.getRadius() + d2.getRadius();
}

float getPenDist(Disc d1, Disc d2) {
    return -(d2.getPosition() - d1.getPosition()).getNorm() - d1.getRadius() - d2.getRadius();
}
```

PhysicsWorld.h :

```
class PhysicsWorld {

protected:
    std::vector<Object*> objectList;

    void resolveCollisions(float duration);

};
```

PhysicsWorld.cpp :

```
#include "PhysicsWorld.h"

void PhysicsWorld::resolveCollisions(float duration) {

    std::vector<Object*>::iterator iter, iter2;

    for (iter = objectList.begin(); iter != objectList.end(); ++iter) {

        for (iter2 = objectList.begin(); iter2 != objectList.end(); ++iter2) {

            if (!(*iter == *iter2))
            {
                if (intersects(**iter, **iter2))
                {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is that the code is running the Intersects(Object*, Object*) function in the resolveCollisions method while I'd like it to run the Intersects(Disc*, Disc*) function.

Please note that these classes are heavily simplified to only include relevant code.
Furthermore, while I'd love to make Object::Intersects(Object o), I can't do that as I can't override it afterward with Disc::Intersects(Disc d).

Thank you very much for any help you can provide !

Comment: It looks like at least 95% of the shown code is completely irrelevant to your question, and it is hard to understand what's being asked with all that irrelevant code. Can you follow Stackoverflow's instructions for creating a [mre], then [edit] your question, accordingly? Everyone else in the world should be able to copy/paste a single chunk of code from your question ***exactly as shown*** into a new, empty file, then compile and reproduce the issue you're asking about.

Comment: `std::vector<Object*>::iterator iter, iter2;` Here `iter`s are essentially `Object**`, so when you dereference them, you will get an `Object`, not a `Disc`. Hence the `intersects` call will use the overload that takes `Object`. The behavior you were thinking was [virtual function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/virtual-functions?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Indeed, I edited my code to only include relevant parts, and I explicited my problem. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As for virtual functions, while I'd love to use them, I can't override an Object::Intersects(Object o) with a Disc::Intersects(Disc d), as Disc is more restrictive than Object.

Comment: "As for virtual functions, while I'd love to use them, I can't override an Object::Intersects(Object o) with a Disc::Intersects(Disc d)" This is a genuinely hard problem, and I wonder what kind of class has it as a beginner level assignment. Your conclusion that you cannot use virtual functions to solve it is incorrect though. Quite the contrary, virtual functions are the commonly used and accepted way to solve it. Try reading up on double dispatch and the visitor pattern. You can do without, but then all your inheritance structure is worthless as you won't be able to use it.

Comment: If the *only* object type you are dealing with is Disc, you don't really need inheritance or virtual functions or `Object` class. Once you add other kinds of objects though, this is no longer true.

Comment: "If the only object type you are dealing with is Disc, you don't really need inheritance or virtual functions or Object class. Once you add other kinds of objects though, this is no longer true." That is completely true, but the point is that we could (and, in latter phases, should) add new types of objects, hence the structure. As for the visitor pattern, it seems quite cumbersome, although I'll implement it if I have to, but for the double dispatch I already tried something similar and had problems with cyclical inclusions. I must have done ti wrong, but I coudn't make it work.

Comment: Visitor pattern and double dispatch are actually very similar and can be thought of as the same idea just implemented a bit differently. The answer from Maciej uses double dispatch. As for inclusion cycles, this is also a common problem. You need to break them by (1) separating the interface and the implementation into .h and .cpp files and (2) always using forward declarations for your dependencies instead of include directives whenever you can get away with it (i.e. when your .h only uses pointers and not actual objects). The .cpp files need to use full include directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** need to call for `Disc`, just cast it. I further assume that you need general solution for multiple shapes, like Disc, Cube, Sphere etc.

So I prepared example for you, that is based on virtual functions and shows how can you choose correct function for Disc and Cube.

```
class Disc;
class Cube;

bool intersectDiscVsDisc(Disc*, Disc*);
bool intersectCubeVsDisc(Cube*, Disc*);
bool intersectCubeVsCube(Cube*, Cube*);

class Object {
    public:
    virtual bool intersects(Object *) = 0;
    virtual bool intersectsVsDisk(Disc *) = 0;
    virtual bool intersectsVsCube(Cube *) = 0;
};

class Disc : public Object {
    virtual bool intersects(Object * another) override 
        { return another->intersectsVsDisk(this); }
    virtual bool intersectsVsDisk(Disc * another) 
        { return intersectDiscVsDisc(this, another); }
    virtual bool intersectsVsCube(Cube * another)
        { return intersectCubeVsDisc(another, this); }

};

class Cube : public Object {
    virtual bool intersects(Object * another) override 
        { return another->intersectsVsCube(this); }
    virtual bool intersectsVsDisk(Disc *another)
        {return intersectCubeVsDisc(this, another); }
    virtual bool intersectsVsCube(Cube *another)
        { return intersectCubeVsCube(this, another); }

};
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much ! Although I feel like it's quite impractical, and it doesn't really respect the Open/Close principle, it does solve my problem, so I'll take it ! Thanks again !

Comment: @Gabriel This is twisted implementation of official Design Pattern "Visitor" (I wanted to make it more similar to your implementation). More e.g. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor/cpp/example